# Many jbuttons with the same onkeypress function

Tags: java, jbutton

I have many jbuttons (around 50+) which can be clicked.

After clicking one the program will check for key inputs and set the button text as the pressed key.

Instead of copy pasting 50 codeblocks to each onkeypressed and onclick event of one button i wanted to use a function in each event.

My code so far (reduced):

```
private JButton attackMoveBtn = new JButton();
private boolean isAlreadyClicked = false;
    private void attackMoveBtnKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                         
        if(attackMoveBtn.getText().equals(Strings.setHotkey)){
            isAlreadyClicked = false;
            attackMoveBtn.setText(String.valueOf(evt.getKeyChar()));
        }
    }                                        

    private void attackMoveBtnMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                           
        if(evt.getButton() == 3){
            isAlreadyClicked = false;
            attackMoveBtn.setText("");
        }else{
            if(!isAlreadyClicked){
                isAlreadyClicked = true;
                attackMoveBtn.setText(Strings.setHotkey);
            }else{
                isAlreadyClicked = false;
                attackMoveBtn.setText("Mouse "+evt.getButton());
            }
        }
    }
```

The only thing that would change for the next button is the JButton itself (**attackMoveBtn** would become **moveBtn** for example)

I tried to use `String compName = evt.getComponent().getName();` to retrieve the name of the button i pressed but i cannot use `"attackMoveBtn".setText()` because dynamic var names are not really supported by java.

Is there a way to get which button was pressed? I could then call a function with the buttonObject as a parameter like `myOnKeyPressFunction(JButton myButton)`

My question would be how i can do dynamic variable names or if my approach is wrong and i should use a different pattern.

Comment: `dynamic variable names` You can't do it in JAVA.

Comment: If same button is performing more than one functionaries then you can check it by its text.  Why you cant use `setText()`?

Comment: Why are you using key press events and mouse event for buttons? Shouldn't you be using ActionListeners instead?

Comment: i need to show the user which key he has pressed (text property) because this will be the hotkey for a game later on. so if he wants to move with S he will press the button (text switches to `set Hotkey`) and then s.

Comment: No need to add `keyListener` on `JButton` just use `JButton.setActionCommand()`

Comment: @peeskillet because i want to set the text of the button to the key that was pressed after the user clicked once on the button.

Comment: i am using netbeans graphic editor to build my gui (i suck at gui programming tbh). thats why i used the onkey events. i will look into setActionCommand().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "Is there a way to get which button was pressed? I could then call a function with the buttonObject as a parameter like myOnKeyPressFunction(JButton myButton)"

Just use `getSource` of the event which returns `Object` and cast `JButton` to it

```
JButton button = (JButton)evt.getSource();
myOnKeyPressFunction(button);
```

---

Fyi, buttons are to be used with `ActionListener` to. If you are using the GUI Editor tool, when right click on the button from the design view, select, `event->action->actionPerformed` and an `ActionListener` will be added for you.

---

> "i am using netbeans graphic editor to build my gui (i suck at gui programming tbh)"

I strongly suggest you ditch the builder tool and go through some tutorial and learn to hand code first. Go through [Creating GUIs with Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/).

Comment: this works perfectly. i forgot about the casting to JButton to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

If its just JButtons using the ActionListener

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    JButton temp = (JButton)e.getSource();
    //do whatever with temp
}
```

If you share the ActionListener with other objects

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
    if(e.getSource() instanceof JButton){
        JButton temp = (JButton)e.getSource();
        //do whatever with temp
    }
}
```